# How do I run a script in Meteor context?

Tags: meteor

This has many applications, but my current application is loading test data into the database from a Cakefile. When I use the mongodb driver to create docs, it adds an `_id` of  `ObjectId("527d9761ae5c03ce1c000001")` instead of a string like `"he3KMaEwsX457ejPW"` that `Meteor.Collection.insert` automatically adds. I would like to be able to run the Cakefile in the Meteor context so that I could simply invoke `CollectionName.insert` instead of using the mongodb driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I do this:

#### Cakefile

```
{spawn} = require 'child_process'

option '-e', '--environment [ENVIRONMENT_NAME]', 'set the environment for `start`'

task 'start', 'start the server', (options) ->
  process.env.METEOR_ENV = options.environment ? 'development'
  spawn 'meteor', [], stdio: 'inherit'
```

Now when I run `cake start`, the `METEOR_ENV` variable will default to `'development'`. You can run start with any string you want here, for example:

```
cake -e production start
```

#### server/initialize.coffee

```
Meteor.startup ->
  environment = process.env.METEOR_ENV ? 'production'
  return if environment is 'production'

  insertCollections = []

  if environment is 'development'
    insertCollections = [
      insertUsers, Meteor.users
      insertGroups, Groups
    ]

  for insert, index in insertCollections by 2
    collection = insertCollections[index + 1]
    insert() if collection.find().count() is 0
```

In this example, after the server starts it looks to see what environment we are in. If it's `'production'`, exit without initializing the database. If the environment is '`development'`, create an array of alternating function and collection names. Then for each pair, call the function only if the collection is empty. In this case, you'd need to define `insertUsers` and `insertGroups` elsewhere.

I like this setup because it automatically populates my database after every `meteor reset`.